# Which process has acquired semaphore

Tags: c++, semaphore

I have created two processes which are accessing same global shared memory. For synchronization purpose, I have used global semaphore. 
Can we find out without debugging(using any windows tool) which process had acquired semaphore?

Comment: I think the question is a little vague. Do you mean from the program itself, or by using OS tools?

Comment: I mean thru some windows tools.

Answer (score 3):

Print a message in your program each time the semaphore is acquired.  Why don't you want you/can't you debug?

Really, without more information about what you're trying to do, this is all that can be said.

Comment: I can't debug because I am using some 3rd party application. And I am releasing the semaphore properly but 3rd party application unable to acquire and saying that unable to get semaphore. Evan I am unable to acquire if i try again after running once.